# Append html code with variables using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

I am having trouble generating html code from jqavascript/jquery in a html template rendered in django. I have to append html code and also insert some values in between. Right now I am doing a crude string append like this

```
var features =['a','b']
for (var i=0;i<features.length;i++){
    var html_code = "<div class = 'feature' <h2>"+features[i]+"</div>
    $("#features").append(html_code)
}
```

For html code

```
<div id="features"></div>
```

What is the right and cleanest way to do this. I know templating is the way to go but there seem to be so many different ways - inline javascript, external library like mustache,handlebar, using django's own template solution - it's very confusing

Comment: Is there a particular reason to not use Django's own templating language?
If the data to insert comes from a client-side request, then you have to use JS, but if your data comes directly from the server, you'll find that django's templating language is very clear and easy to use. Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/ "Django template language docs")

Comment: yes, the data is coming from client side only - hence not using Django template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indeed a wide range of options for this. I'd make the decision based on how many times do you need to change the DOM in your website. If it is very often, I'd think about using a library to make it more readable/maintainable (React + ReactDOM is very lightweight, 31,8kB gzipped according to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Restuta/cda69e50a853aa64912d))

If you have to insert the html in one or two places and you care about performance, check [this article](https://howchoo.com/code/learn-the-slow-and-fast-way-to-append-elements-to-the-dom)

Keep in mind that in each iteration you are traversing the DOM to find the `#features` element and that's very inefficient. It'd be better to perform the query outside the loop and store it in a const, or do it like shown below.

Also, it might be a typo, but you have a sneaky h2 tag there `<div class = 'feature' <h2>`. Modern browsers try to fix HTML errors but you should not rely on it because they have to do a lot of guesswork and it might break your layout.

### TL;DR

Fastest way is with vanilla JS:

```js
const features = ['a', 'b']
const c = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (let i=0; i<features.length; i++) {
    const e = document.createElement("div");
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(features[i]);
    e.appendChild(textNode);
    e.className = "feature";
    c.appendChild(e);
}
document.querySelector('#features').appendChild(c);
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. I am adding only a few divs so not concerned about the efficiency, however the html code was for illustration.Its a much larger html and key concern is readability. Hence was wondering if inline templating is an option

Comment: Yes, it is always an option. But if you are concerned about readability (and maintanibility) you should consider adding your JS as a static asset in your django template and place your javascript there. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: gorgeous! just what i needed